# How can I allow a specific section to have multi selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on step by step order, and I am so thankful for having received plenty of help from others already. I'm still not done asking, though!

My steps are divided into different `<section>` and I would like to give a `<section>` a `class="multiple"` to allow this specific section to have multiple selections. I use `.selected` to determine either the if `<li>` has been selected or not.

This is my current code:

```
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // remove selected class from links after the current one
   $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('li').removeClass('selected');
   // remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
   $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected').end().toggleClass('selected');
   var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-id'));
   if ($target.length) {
       // hide any steps after the current one that may be shown
       $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('.step').not($target).removeClass('active');
       // toggle display of selected step
       $target.toggleClass('active', $(this).hasClass('selected'));
   } else {
       console.log('do something else to end this thing');
   }
})
```

So my question is, what can I do with my code to make `<section class="multiple>` allowing multiple selected items?

[This is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/979aL2g5/6/). Click on the items to get the last step, which should be the section that allows multiple selections.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will you only have a `.multiple` class on the last step, or in other words, on a step that doesn't have any steps after it?

Comment: @MichaelCoker There will be one more step after atleast one li has been selected. Sorry for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `.multiple` before removing the `.selected` class from the menu `li`'s. https://jsfiddle.net/979aL2g5/7/

```js
$('li').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $parent = $(this).closest('section')
  // remove selected class from links after the current one
  $parent.nextAll('section').find('li').removeClass('selected');
  // remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  (! $parent.hasClass('multiple')) && $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
  var $target = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  if ($target.length) {
    // hide any steps after the current one that may be shown
    $parent.nextAll('section').find('.step').not($target).removeClass('active');
    // toggle display of selected step
    $target.toggleClass('active', $(this).hasClass('selected')); 
  } else {
    console.log('do something else to end this thing');
  }
})
```

```css
body { color: #333; }
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.step {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  background: #27ae60 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.bananas {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.bananas.special.selected {
  background: #3498db !important;
}

.hi {
  color: #27ae60;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #27ae60;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.hi.special {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
}

#same_target {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #9b59b6;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#same_target p {
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.nomarking {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h1>First step, please choose something</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="one">
          Sprite
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="two">
          King Kong
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="three">
          Astronauts
        </li>
      </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="one" class="step">
    <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">Sprite</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking " data-id="third">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="step">
      <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">King Kong</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="three" class="step">
      <h1>Second step for <span class="hi">Astronauts</span> - choose another</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          McDonalds
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          Burger King
        </li>
        <li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="third">
          Tim Hortons
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="multiple">
    <div id="third" class="step">
      <h1>Multiple <span class="hi special">selections</span> section - choose under</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Hamburger
        </li>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Coffee
        </li>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Stackoverflow
        </li>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Australia
        </li>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Oldschool
        </li>
        <li class="bananas special nomarking">
          Deadpool
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is super. It is almost on the edge of personal frustration to see that all you change is a bit more than one line to achieve what I'm looking for. I have alot to learn. Thanks again, hero!

Comment: @superladremi you're welcome! I've been doing this for about 9 years. Beginners usually have to throw every tool they have at a problem and often just start changing stuff until something works. Gurus can go in with surgical precision, immediately spot the problem, and make just the tiny change needed. It comes with experience is all. And I've already worked on your project a few times so I'm somewhat familiar with it :)

Comment: Absolutely, if I had those 9 years I would probably answer instead of asking, but right now that's where I am. Yes, you have worked on it a few times, I wont forget, so thank you for helping me once again :o)

Answer (score 0):

Among the possibilities I like these two approaches:

1. Assign `class="single"` to previous sections and create two similar functions, one triggered on `$('li .single').on('click',function(e)...` and the other with `$('li .multiple').on('click',function(e)...`.  The first you already have it. Modify the second taking `$(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected')` out so you can select multiple items.
2. Second option would be to keep the single '$('li .single').on('click',function(e)...' but put actions on the scope of an IF/THEN to check if the user clicked on a single or multiple section and again don't `$(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected')` if inside the `.multiple` section

Answer (score 0):

I would change this:

```
// remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
$(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected').end().toggleClass('selected');
```

to this:

```
// remove selected from siblings if not multiple
if (!$(this).closest('section').hasClass('multiple')) {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
}
// toggle current selected class
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```